# Finding specific value inside an Array (not List)

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning about arrays and I did quiet a few experiments, most of them went well, however now I'm stuck.
What I want to archive is, find if an specific value (String, int or whatever), exists inside an Array and if it does, use that value for something i.e the code below which I basically count how many times that value was present inside the array:

```
package arraysOnly;
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayContainsString
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
        {       
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int arraySize = 0;
            int wordCount = 0;

            System.out.println("How many words are you gonna type?: ");
            arraySize = sc.nextInt();

            String[] words = new String[arraySize];     // Simple array, the size of which will be decided from the user-input

            for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter your " + (count+1) + ": ");
                words[count] = sc.next();
            }

            //Basically this is the part I'm having troubles
             if(in_array("ubt", $words)
            {
                 wordCount++;
            }
        }
}
```

I know about this,

```
if(Arrays.asList(words).contains("ubt"));
```

which basically converts the array into an List / ArrayList or whatever, however I want to treat this as an array only if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over array

```
for (String str : array){
  if(str.equals("ubt")){    
   wordCount++;
 }    
}
```

**Edit:**

It's just equivalent to a normal for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].equals("ubt")){    
       wordCount++;
     } 
}
```

Comment: Aside from the typo, this doesn't have the same behavior as the OP had in their current solution.

Comment: Is the above code is  not replacement for `if(Arrays.asList(words).contains("ubt"));` ?

Comment: No, it has different behavior for multiple matches within the array.

Comment: What's the ' String str : array '  part do? I just want to make sure I'm not "cheating" by converting the array into an ArrayList or whatever else.

Comment: No. It just iterating over the array. Going to edit that part. The current way is called as `enhanced for loop`

Comment: Alright mate, thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated <3

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution

```
public static boolean contains(String toFind, String[] strings) {
    for (String str : strings) {
        if (str.equals(toFind)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT:
To increase it after the user inputs a word, use this in the loop:

```
System.out.println("Enter your " + (count+1) + ": ");
words[count] = sc.next();
if (words[count].equals("ubt")) wordCount++;
```

Comment: I'm confused here, how do I add this to my code to increase the value of wordCount, everytime the specific word is typed?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking for another thing xD. After words[count] = sc.next();, add 'if (words[count].equals("ubt")) wordCount++;

Comment: hat scans the input however, I want to scan the array itself, after all the wanted words are typed. Which means all the input will be done and the array will be filled with elements, after that I want to scan it and find if the specific value exists, I tried this however (as suggested from @SURESH ATTA. And I think this might be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks anyways, I'll write down your code down for future personal reference.

Answer (score 2):

An array is the wrong data structure; a `Set` is the weapon of choice:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>()
for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++) {
    System.out.println("Enter your " + (count+1) + ": ");
    words.add(sc.next());
}

if (words.contains("ubt"))
    wordCount++;
}
```

The `contains()` method of a `HashSet` completes in constant time not matter how large the set is. Although performance is irrelevant for small input sizes like this usage, it's good to get in the habit of choosing the right tools for the job. It also makes your code cleaner.

Generally speaking, don't use arrays unless you absolutely have to; they are only rarely used in commercial code.

Comment: I know it might not be the best, I mean ArrayList are just perfect for almost any occasion however, I gotta learn all the corners of Java including Arrays and whatever they can and cannot do. I'm learning for my college Exam.

Comment: @Bohemian could you elaborate on "how arrays are rarely used in commercial code", why is this? do you have an article I can look at to learn more?

Comment: @coderrick arrays have no "convenience" about them - you must micro-manage them. Collections on the other hand have lots of instance methods and utility method support, and they are just easier to use (not the least of which is they grow in size automatically on demand), They are virtually as fast as arrays (being backed by them), and let you get on with writing code that matters.